# How can i make a field with a datatype Varchar be a date in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, database, date, select, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake and I have a field with a datatype VARCHAR and the values in that field are for example: `2/10/17, 9/7/18, 1/23/19`.

I trying to convert that field into a Date using this script:

```
select To_Date(Field_name) from CONCUR
```

However i get this message:
`Date '' is not recognized`

Answer (score 1):

You need a format specification as a second argument to `to_date()` (otherwise it defaults to session parameter `DATE_INPUT_FORMAT`, which is probably not what you want):

```
to_date(field_name, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

You may also want to use [`try_to_date()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html), that returns `null` when the conversion fails rather than raising an error as `to_date()` does.

Answer (score 0):

To_date should be used with the format like below

select to_date('02/14/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), date('02/14/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY');

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html

Thanks
Palash